# Deployed Infopath form not displayed in browser

Tags: 2010, infopath

I'm using SP 2010.when i try to create a new docment from my infopath form i get the error "**This form template is not enabled for viewing in the browser**."
I have :

1. created an infopath with codebehind
2. changed its security level to "Full trust"
3. made sure it was browser compatible
4. published to network path

Then using the form from step (4) I published a content type using a feature, following [this tutorial](http://www.stuartroberts.net/index.php/2010/12/14/programatically-register-infopath-form-for-web-browsing-in-sharepoint/)

still im faced with that error, what did i do wrong?

**InfoPath Module**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="ActionTracking" RootWebOnly="TRUE" Url="FormServerTemplates">
<File Path="ActionTracking.xsn" Url="ActionTracking.xsn" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>
</Module>
</Elements>
```

**Content Type**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Form (0x010101) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x01010100565205e23b9b41269f62078f7f9c13af"
               Name="ActionTrackingContentType"
               Group="Custom Content Types"
               Description="My Content Type"
               Inherits="TRUE"
                 RequireClientRenderingOnNew="FALSE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
    </FieldRefs>
    <DocumentTemplate TargetName="/FormServerTemplates/ActionTracking.xsn" />
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Have you activated it to the target site collection in central admit? General settings, and manage infopath forms

Answer (score 1):

I may be completely mistaken but my understanding is that the browser forms do not require a copy of infopath to allow a user to work with the form.  Only certain types of built-in functions within infopath are allowed in web based form.  I don't believe any back end coding is permitted.

This may have some useful information:
https://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/infopath-help/web-browser-compatibility-in-infopath-forms-services-HA010204085.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will need to grab the copy from the published location, can't use the one you published from originally. Up load that to the managed forms,, (causes iis reset) then activate to the Web app/ site collection